# AngularJS Animate: Run two animation types concurrently

Tags: css, angularjs, animation, angularjs-directive

I am trying to run two different animation types concurrently - a fadein for the data elements and have the background expand (height) at the same time. The issue is that the fade doesn't appear to be working at all. If I remove the height animation, then the fade will work. But I can't seem to be able to get both to run concurrently.

Here's the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/073752?p=preview).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

These ways of doing animations aren't compatible you need to choose to use one or the other when you're combining animations.  The TweenMax code manipulates CSS and properties of elements to achieve animations with lots of control.  The angular $animate service just adds and removes CSS classes and basically watches for transitions that are occurring in the process to allow you to control the entire animation using CSS.  The problem is if TweenMax is also modifying the classes or directly changing the styles it's going to botch the css you setup for $animate.

[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate/service/$animate](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate/service/%24animate)

http://www.greensock.com/category/javascript/#